# npm install bcrypt@3.0.6 fails with node 6.12.1

Tags: node.js

We are having problems running `npm install` - the following error occurs.

```
Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@12.13.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Comment: Are you running `npm install bcrypt@3.0.6` or `npm install` ? Also, this is an error from bcrypt, you should create an issue on their repo : https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues. Probably related that this issue, by the way : https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for your reference.
Version Compatibility of Bcrypt:

```
Node Version    Bcrypt Version
0.4             <= 0.4
0.6, 0.8, 0.10  >= 0.5
0.11            >= 0.8
4               < 2.1
8               >= 1.0.3
10              >= 3
```

Comment: Version Compatibility
Node Version  Bcrypt Version
0.4  <= 0.4
0.6, 0.8, 0.10  >= 0.5
0.11  >= 0.8
4  <= 2.1.0
8  >= 1.0.3
10, 11  >= 3
12 (nightly)  >= 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your node_modules folder either manually or via terminal run: `$ rm -rf node_modules`, and rerun `$ npm install`.
If that doesn't help, try reinstall the module by removing the node_modules folder as before and remove the bcrypt from your package.json and then run the `$ npm install` and `$ npm install bcrypt`.

in last resort, you can try see if this module works as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs